# checkbox says only "on" all the time

Tags: php

this is how I have 2 checkbox and I do not want that you should only click on them simultaneously. it must only be possible to click on one at a time!. in the present to when I clicked the news, so it must enter a number in there to write "on". I would like to later be sure it is entered into the database.

the problem is that it appears to say "on" no matter what!?

```
<form action="#" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Emne</td>
                            <td>Vigtigt: <input type="checkbox" name="vigtigt" class="new"> Nyhede: <input type="checkbox" name="nyhede" class="new"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Title</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50" class="new"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tekst</td>
                            <td><textarea name="tekst" cols="20" rows="15" class="new"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret Blog" class="new"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST["opret"]))
                    {
                        if($_POST["vigtigt"] != "")
                        {
                            echo $_POST["vigtigt"];
                            echo "<br />";
                            echo $_POST["nyhede"];
                        }
                        elseif ($_POST["nyhede"] != "")
                        {
                            echo $_POST["vigtigt"];
                            echo "<br />";
                            echo $_POST["nyhede"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Fejl!";   
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </form>
```

Comment: try using radio instead of checkboxes and use the same name attribute

Comment: you must set value to checkboxes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a `value` attribute for it to:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vigtigt" class="new" value="MyValueHere">
```

This way you will receive its value when its checked.

**Edit:**

To have only one selected at a time you will have to use `type="radio"` and give them the same name and different values.

```
<input type="radio" name="vigtigt" class="new" value="MyValueHere">
<input type="radio" name="vigtigt" class="new" value="MyOtherValueHere">
```

Comment: Thanks for help. How do I do so that you can only choice one of the 2?

Comment: @JesperPetersen use a radio box instead of a checkbox with the same name

Comment: Thanks again!.. :) and gj for you!!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of checkboxes if to provide a group of options from which any number can be selected.

If you want a single option to be selected, use radio buttons (or a select element).

The value attribute (of the checked radio / selected option) determines the value that will be submitted. `on` is the default value for checkboxes which is used if you forget to specify a specific value.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="vigtigt" class="new"> Vigtigt</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="nyhede" class="new">  Nyhede</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. How do I do so that you can only choice one of the 2?

Comment: You give the radio buttons the same name, as per the example in the answer.